# OpenSSL iOS thread safety issue

Tags: ios, openssl, evp-cipher

I'm using the following openssl functions:

- PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1
- EVP_BytesToKey
- EVP_aes_256_cbc
- EVP_sha1
- EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
- EVP_EncryptInit_ex
- EVP_DecryptInit_ex
- EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
- EVP_DecryptUpdate
- EVP_DecryptFinal_ex
- EVP_EncryptUpdate
- EVP_EncryptFinal_ex

When decrypting data on a background thread, there are no issues if the data size is *fairly* small.

For data around 500 kilobytes the decrypt routine will always crash on `EVP_DecryptUpdate` but is fine on the main thread.

What gives?

Comment: http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG1 <-- Did you satisfy this?

Comment: how are you **using** this code?  can you show us your code that makes use of these functions?

Comment: @borrden, thanks, I did not. When I read "On Windows and many Unix systems, OpenSSL automatically uses the multi-threaded versions of the standard libraries. If your platform is not one of these, consult the INSTALL file", I'm guessing iOS isn't one of these platforms... ok will take a look at that.

Comment: @Nate, will edit the question with the details in a bit

Comment: @borrrden check this: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html#notes it appears thread support is enabled... anyway, will look into trying it with the callbacks to see if it helps

Comment: @Rls Actually I was referring to *only using a connection from one thread at a time*.  If your operation takes too long, then you are probably trying to perform two at once, resulting in that error.  Even with multi-thread support enabled, it is not truly "thread-safe" in the sense that you want it to be.